# Need to write a function that computes the UV index

Tags: visible-light, atmospheric-science

I have found a lot of people talking about how to compute the UV index, but have not found an example that shows the actual equations, so I could adapt them into an algorithm.

Probably the closest is this example [here](http://dermatology-s10.cdlib.org/DOJvol6num1/original/sunscreens/kinney.html).

The most confusing part of the process is why there are so many cases that present hypothetical data rather than a real example. For instance, [here](http://www.epa.gov/sunwise/uvicalc.html) is the EPA's explanation. They seem to compute a real number. But they say the weighing factors are fake.

Answer (score 2):

This is a part answer in regards to the weighing factors:

According to the Smithsonian Environmental Research Centre's page ["How is the UV-Index Calculated?"](http://www.serc.si.edu/labs/photobiology/UVIndex_calculation.aspx), the weighing factor are not so much made up, but is

> weighted according to how human skin responds to each wavelength; it is more important to protect people from wavelengths that harm skin than from wavelengths that do not damage people's skin.

This weighting function is based on the McKinlay-Diffey Erythema action spectrum, defined in this NOAA article ["Instantaneous UV Index and Daily UV Dose Calculations"](http://www.esrl.noaa.gov/gmd/grad/neubrew/docs/UVindex.pdf) and is wavelength dependent, with the weighting for wavelengths (note, the NOAA article has a step by step mathematical procedure).

- less than 298nm = 1.
- between 298nm and 328nm weighted by $10^{0.094(298-\lambda)}$
- between 328nm and 400nm weighted as $10^{0.015(139-\lambda)}$
- for wavelengths 400nm and above, they are weighted as 0

Giving the action spectra as:

[image: McKinlay and Diffey Action Spectra]

Image source: ["Solar ultraviolet radiation effects on biological systems"](http://www.ciesin.org/docs/001-503/001-503.html) (Diffey, 1991).

Comment: I hadn't looked at this in a long time. Not sure why I checked this answer. I up voted it and that was deserved, but this is not an answer.